# Is there a condition for the nilradical to equal the derived subalgebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Suppose $\mathfrak{g}$ is a finite dimensional Lie algebra over $\mathbb{C}$. Is there a condition for when $\mathfrak{r}=NR(\mathfrak{g})=[\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{g}]$?

I realize that $[\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{g}] \subset \mathfrak{r}$, so I suppose when I'm asking is for when $\mathfrak{r} \subset [\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{g}]$.

Comment: For a general Lie algebra, there is no reason that $[\mathfrak g,\mathfrak g]\subset\mathfrak r$. For example for semisimple $\mathfrak g$ you get $[\mathfrak g,\mathfrak g]=\mathfrak g$ and $\mathfrak r=\{0\}$.

Comment: $[g,g]\subset r$ iff $g$ is solvable

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, $[\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{g}] \subset NR(\mathfrak{g})$ says that $\mathfrak{g}$ is solvable (over characteristic zero), and $[\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{g}] = NR(\mathfrak{g})$ is a genuine condition for a solvable Lie algebra. The oscillator Lie algebra does satisfy this, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1369516/realizing-the-oscillator-algebra-as-a-matrix-lie-algebra), but the Heisenberg Lie algebra does not, of course (no nilpotent Lie algebra does). This is a start to find some sufficient conditions for having equality.